# how to show "pushButton" creating in C++ code inside UI

Tags: c++, qt

The idea is that I want to create a button in the C++ code and this will be displayed in the UI.

I have an `nsPushButton` class which inherits from `QPushButton`. when I launch the application the button is not displayed in the UI.

> nsPushButton.h

```
    class nsPushButton : public QPushButton {
    public:
        nsPushButton(QString text);

        void click();

    };
```

> nsPushButton.cpp

```
    nsPushButton::nsPushButton(QString text)
    : QPushButton(text) 
    {
    }

    void nsPushButton::click() {
        qInfo() << "button clicked !";
    }
```

> QtWidgetsApplication1.h

```
    class QtWidgetsApplication1 : public QWidget
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        QtWidgetsApplication1(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
        void create(QString text);

    private:
        Ui::QtWidgetsApplication1Class ui;
    };
```

> QtWidgetsApplication1.cpp

```
    QtWidgetsApplication1::QtWidgetsApplication1(QWidget *parent)
        : QWidget(parent)
    {
        ui.setupUi(this);
    }

    void QtWidgetsApplication1::create(QString text) {
        nsPushButton* button = new nsPushButton(text);
    }
```

> main

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        QtWidgetsApplication1 w;

        w.create("test");

        w.show();
        return a.exec();
    }
```

Comment: You need to add your button to the layout you have in your widget

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a layout to the main widget and add buttons in the layout.

QtWidgetsApplication1.h

```
class QtWidgetsApplication1 : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QtWidgetsApplication1(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    void create(QString text);

private:
    Ui::QtWidgetsApplication1Class ui;
    QVBoxLayout *m_layout;
};
```

QtWidgetsApplication1.cpp

```
QtWidgetsApplication1::QtWidgetsApplication1(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    m_layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    this->setLayout(m_layout);

}

void QtWidgetsApplication1::create(QString text) {
    nsPushButton* button = new nsPushButton(text);
    m_layout->addWidget(button);
}
```

Comment: thank u for ur reply. the problem is when I add button to a layout I can not control its position via `setGeometry()` ?!